# C typedef struct redefinition, different basic types

Tags: struct, reference, typedef

First time posting here. I have problem about referencing a typedef struct from separate files. Example:

main.c //menus and variables declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "person.h"
#include "person.c"

person persondata[50] ;
```

---

person.h //typedef struct{...}person;

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
}person;
```

---

person.c //functions

```
extern persondata[];

void copy()
{
    strcpy(persondata[0].name, "John");
}
```

I keep getting error: left of ".name" must have struct/union type and redefinition, different basic types

How am I supposed to fix this reference?

Comment: Is this all the code ? Do you  #include "person.h" in your person.c file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

```
extern person persondata[];
```

instead.
This should do the trick.

If you don't give it the correct type, the compiler won't know that persondata is an array of persons.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would `#include "person.h"` so as to make the declaration of `person` visible, and then you would change the persondata declaration to:

```
extern person persondata[];
```

... i.e. specify its type.

Comment: You don't need to use 'struct'

Comment: Thanks, just noticed that myself. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`extern persondata[];` is implicitly equivalent to `extern int persondata[];` (the compiler assumes `int` if you don't specify a type).  You need `extern person persondata[];`.

Also, the compiler needs to be able to see the definition of `person` in person.c, so add `#include "person.h"` at the top of the file.

Comment: person.h doesn't have a declaration for `persondata`, so the extern line should be corrected rather than removed (or the declaration should be added to person.h).

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
#include "person.h"
person persondata[10];
```